# Is there a way to update only the trigger date on a local user notification in Swift - UNUserNotificationCenter

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, unusernotificationcenter

The following code successfully updates a local user notification that matches the identifier, `notificationID`.

Is there a way to update just the trigger date and leave the title and the body intact?

```
func updateNotificationWithID(notificationID:String){
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    var request : UNNotificationRequest?

    center.getPendingNotificationRequests{ notifications in
        for notificationRequest in notifications{
            if notificationRequest.identifier == notificationID{
                request = notificationRequest
            }
        }
        
        let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        let components = calendar.dateComponents([.month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: .now.addingTimeInterval(60))
        let newTrigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: false)

        let notificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        notificationContent.title = "Modified Title"
        
        notificationContent.body = "Modified body"
        let updateRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: request!.identifier, content: notificationContent, trigger: newTrigger)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(updateRequest, withCompletionHandler: { (error) in
            print("successfully updated")
            if error != nil {
                print(" Couldn't update notification \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            }
        })
    }
}
```